# String Manupulation without any array list or tree?

Tags: java, string, substring

I Have Some input as String. i need to do some following Stuffs :

1. Words should be printed increasing order of the length;
2. Words repeated more than once are ignored.
3. After the same size of the words size of the words to be printed .

For Example : `Input : the Black lion was bigger than the red lion;`

```
Output : the was 3 than black 4 ... so on....till the end!
```

I have tried with Array List and sorted them. but result is not that accurate as the question asked. 
**Can anyone help to implement the result without list or tree or Regex.**

```
import java.util.*;
class Sorted implements Comparator<String> {

    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        if (o1.length() < o2.length()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (o1.length() > o2.length()) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}public class smallToLarge {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Scanner o = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the Sentence : ");
        String sentance = o.nextLine().toLowerCase();
        String[] str = sentance.split("\\s+");
        Arrays.sort(str, new Sorted());
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
            if (!arrList.contains(str[i])) {
                arrList.add(str[i]);
            }
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < arrList.size(); j++) {
            System.out.print(arrList.get(j) + " " + arrList.get(j).length() + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using recursion?

Comment: Nope not sure how to implement! Since it needs to be sorted and duplicates needs to be removed. @Goion can you help me?

Comment: If you don't want to use array list or something why don't you try something like regex?

Comment: @ChathurangaKalana have a Challenge to do with Standard String API only . and how to implement with Regex?

Comment: You can remove duplicates first and the worry about sorting

Comment: @Goion Can you help me with complete solution? its all over my head

Comment: "Can you help me with complete solution?" - well, didn't you write _you_ "have a challenge"? If so _you_ should try to solve it. We can help with pointers etc. but it is you who should come up with the "complete" solution. Btw, I don't quite get your 3rd requirement: after which "same size of the words" should what "size of the words" be printed? I get that "lion" should be ignored because it is repeated, but why should "black" be ignored and "the" not? And where does that `4` after `than black` come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being dumb, one has to walk more. Here I use one data structure: a StringBuilder to
collect words of the same length, as one can then easily check for duplicate words.

```
int lastSize = 0;
for (;;) {
    int nextSize = determineNextSize(lastSize, input);
    if (nextSize <= lastSize) {
        break;
    }
    StringBuilder words = new StringBuilder();
    collectUniqueWordsOfLength(input, nextSize, words);
    lastSize = nextSize;
    System.out.print(words + lastSize + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

The input string walking methods:

```
int determineNextSize(String input, int size) {
    int minSize = -1;
    int p0 = 0;
    while (p0 < innput.length()) {
        int p = input.indexOf(' ', p0);
        if (p == -1) {
            p = input.length();
        }
        int wordSize = p - p0;
        if (wordSize  > size && (minSize == -1 || wordSize  < minSize)) {
            minSize = wordSize ;
        }
        p0 = p + 1;
    }
    return minSize;
}

void collectUniqueWordsOfLength(String input, int size, StringBuilder words) {
    int p0 = 0;
    while (p0 < innput.length()) {
        int p = input.indexOf(' ', p0);
        if (p == -1) {
            p = input.length();
        }
        int wordSize = p - p0;
        if (wordSize  == size)) {
            String word = input.substring(p0, p) + " ";
            if (!words.toString().contains(word)) {
                words.append(word);
            }
        }
        p0 = p + 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you time and help. i am a beginner in java programming. i tried your code getting few errors!!. `if (!words.contains(word)) {
                words.append(word);
            } ` **The method contains(String) is undefined for the type StringBuilder** and  **can you help me what is for(;;)?**.

Comment: Changed it into `words.toString().contains(word)`

Comment: still getting error `String index out of range: -12
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at abstractExp.A.collectUniqueWordsOfLength(Strplace.java:38)
 at abstractExp.Strplace.main(Strplace.java:63)` @Joop Eggen

Comment: Corrected to `input.substring(p0, p)` as substring takes start position and exclusive end position.

Comment: Getting the output as `3 4 5 6 `  Expecting the output something like this `the was 3 than black 4` ... so on` @ Joop Eggen

Comment: Facing the problem in case 3 of the question!

Comment: `System.out.print(words + lastSize + " ");` should print the words (ending in a space) followed by the length of every word.

Comment: same output. no change @Joop Eggen

Comment: I should apologize not really having run my code; as the problem is more academic, a puzzle. Now it would be time for you to start debugging. If you comment out `collectUniqueWordsOfLength` all word sizes should be printed.

Answer (score 2):

If it's okay for you to use streams, you can do it simply like:

```
String input = "the Black lion was bigger than the red lion";
Pattern.compile("\\s+")
       .splitAsStream(input)
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length,TreeMap::new,Collectors.toSet()))
       .forEach((k,v)->{ System.out.print(v + " " + k + " ");});

//to get the output
//[the, red, was] 3 [than, lion] 4 [Black] 5 [bigger] 6
```

Explanation:

- Split your input at each space
- Collect them grouping by their length
- into a TreeMap to sort them ascending
- toSet to remove duplicates

If you don't want the strings in brackets change last line to:

```
.forEach((k,v)->{ System.out.print(String.join(" ", v) + " " + k + " ");});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple proof of concept using Streams/Collectors:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<String>();
  String sentence = "the Black lion was bigger than the red lion";
  var words = sentence.split("\\s");
  // take all the words
  var sortedByLength = Arrays.stream(words)
    // group by string length
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(String::length, 
      // sort by string length
      TreeMap::new, 
      // unique words
      Collectors.toSet()));
  // for every length-List(word) pair
  for(var entry : sortedByLength.entrySet())
  {
    // for every word in List(word)
    for(var word : entry.getValue())
    {
      System.out.print(word+" ");
    }
    System.out.print(entry.getKey()+" ");
  }
}
```

Output:

```
the red was 3 than lion 4 Black 5 bigger 6
```

You'll have to extend it to read input as you wish.

Here's a similar proof of concept, not using Lists, Tree(set/map)s, or Regex:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  String sentence = "the Black lion was bigger than the red lion";
  var words = sentence.split("\\s");
  if(words.length == 0)
    return;
  int nulls = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
  {
    for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++)
    {
      if(words[i].equals(words[j]))
      {
        words[i] = null;
        nulls++;
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  var noDupes = new String[words.length - nulls];
  int index = 0;
  for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++)
  {
    if(words[i] != null)
      noDupes[index++] = words[i];
  }
  Arrays.sort(noDupes, Comparator.comparingInt(String::length));
  for(int i = 0; i < noDupes.length; i++)
  {
    System.out.print(noDupes[i]+" ");
    if(i == noDupes.length - 1)
    {
      System.out.println(noDupes[i].length());
    }
    else if(noDupes[i+1].length() > noDupes[i].length())
    {
      System.out.print(noDupes[i].length()+" ");
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
was the red 3 than lion 4 Black 5 bigger 6
```

It's probably massively inefficient compared to the first solution, but it works.

Comment: Thanks for the Solution. But looking to Crack without List or Tree. only by using Standard String API

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
String str =  "the Black lion was bigger than the red lion";

str = Arrays.stream( str.split("\\s+")).distinct().collect(Collectors.joining(" ") );

    for (int i = 0 ; i <= str.length() ; i++) {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w{"+i+"}\\b").matcher(str);
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.print(m.group(0) +" ");
        }
    }
```

This is using regex you will have to modify some changes like to print the word  length.
hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to answer based on how I understand your requirements which I'll list first:

1. The words should be sorted by length and probably lexically as well (so "red" before "the" etc.)
2. Words that appear more than twice ("repeated more than once") should be ignored
3. The words should be printed and whenever the length changes the length of the previous group should be printed

To achieve that you could do the following:

1. split the text into individual words creating an array or list (you might want to split on whitespace and punctuation)
2. iterate once to "convert" every word into its lowercase form (this could be inlined if necessary)
3. sort the array/list of words by using a comparator that compares the length first and if the length is equal compares the strings lexially
4. iterate over the words again and collect them into a `LinkedHashMap` where the word is the key and the value is a counter for that word
5. iterate over that map's entry set, skip any word whose counter is greater than 2 (or 1 depending on how requirement no. 2 is to be interpreted)
6. keep track of the length of the previous word and whenever it differs from the length of the current word print either length (depending on whether you need to print the length before or after the words themselves)